# oci.dll is not linked

Tags: windows-server-2003, oracle10g

I have an application developed in Delphi 5 accessing Oracle 10g and I´m getting the error `OCI.DLL IS NOT LINKED` when I try to save data in database. My ODAC version is 6.50 and I'm running the application on a Windows Server 2003 SP2. I installed the Oracle Client 8i and 10g and oci.dll exists in both oracle_homes.

Does anyone know why I am receiving this error?

Comment: OCI.DLL errors happen when the executable cant find an oracle client installation.
do you have an environment variable named "ORACLE_HOME"?
and if so does it direct you to the oracle client installation?

Answer (score 0):

As an outside shot, I'd run [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) against the OCI.DLL and make sure that it doesn't have any unresolved dependencies.